# Expected Workload

Tags: probability, expected-value

I can produce 1 widget per day. I have a full materials bin which allows me to produce exactly N widgets. On a given day my bin may be refilled (so I again have the capacity to make N widgets) with probability P. This refill can only happen once on a given day. What is the average number of days  I work until I have used all my materials (how many widgets will I make on average)?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Mostly lots of tinkering in excel, trying to spot a pattern. I did figure out that if I am given the materials for K widgets upon refill (vs refilled up to N) the expected number of widgets is N/(1-PK). In this scenario the bin is infinite. If I had to guess I think a recursion relation could be set up, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Think about what is necessary for you to stop making widgets:  There must be $N$ days in a row of no replenishment.  What's the probability of that?  On each day:  $1-P$.  On $N$ successive days:  $(1-P)^N$.  Now that can happen starting on day $1$, or on day $2$, or ...  Can you continue?

Comment: I am finding some more difficulties. Interestingly enough I am running into Fibonacci sequences of order N. In finding the number of sequences of days up until the "successive days of length N with no replenish". I.e. if N in the problem is 5, counting the number of ways it can happen on day 1, 2... are 1,2,4,8,16,31,61. Even harder, to find the probability for each sequence for a given N would require knowing the number or average number of replenishment. I do not see a pattern for that (not on OEIS). Is there another way to attack this problem?

Comment: You never need to know how many parts are added on a given day.  Your problem states that the supply is "replenished."  If you haven't run out, it makes no difference... you're "reset" to full parts.  (At least that is what you've written.). I see no reason whatsoever that Fibonacci arises here.

Comment: Ok, Think I got it. the sum of all the different probabilities is:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (1-(1-P)^N)^i(1-P)^N=1$$
So the expected number of Widgets (days) would be
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (1-(1-P)^N)^i(1-P)^N(i+N)$$ which equals $$\frac{N(1-P)^N-(1-P)^N+1}{(1-P)^N}$$
Does this look to be correct? It does not match up with my little simulation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. For N=6, chance of making 7 widgets would be getting replenished on the first day, and then never again until you hit 0. $P(1-P)^6$. With the formula above it would be $(1-(1-P)^6)(1-P^6)$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extended hint.

The only way to be depleted is if the final $N$ days of a period are not replenished.  The probability of that happening is $(1-P)^N$.  Moreover, the day immediately *before* those final $N$ must be a *replenish* day (otherwise you would be depleted earlier), and this happens with probability $P$.  So we are certain that the "end game" or termination criterion is $N+1$ days in which a replenishment day is followed by the final $N$ days having *no* replenishment.  So there will be a factor of $P(1-P)^N$ for all sequences longer then $N$.  (The probability for terminating in exactly $N$ days is of course $(1-P)^N$.

(We see immediately that the minimum number of days of working is $N$.  After all, that's how many days we have parts at the beginning.)

Now we have to consider longer sequences.  Let's call the full candidate length of days $k$, and define $k_s = k - (N+1)$ (for the preliminary sequence).  We will be working for the full $k$ days so long as we have any number of days *before* the final $N+1$ *so long as* there is no consecutive set of $N$ days with no replenishment.  (That ensures we're still working $N+1$ days from the end.) Thus we are interested in the $k_s = k-(N+1)$ "non-terminating" days.

Let's call $k_r$ the number of *replenished* days (in the "non-terminating" days) and $k_n$ the number of *non-replenished* days.  Of course $k_r + k_n = k_s$. It is a straightforward application of the binomial theorem to specify the probability of getting any given number of $k_r$ (and thus $k_n$) of the $k_s$ days.  We also know (from the binomial theorem) what the *probability* of that sequence will be.

The tricky part is to subtract off the anomalous "terminating" sequences occuring within the $k_s$ days, that is, ones that have $k_u \geq 5$.  You need to use combinatorics to find this value (and then its probability, which is straightforward).

At the end, you'll have an expression for the probability of having a sequence of length $k_s$, and thus the full duration of $k$.  Call that probability $P_k$.  To find the average number of days, calculate:

$${\cal E}(x) =\sum\limits_{k= N+1}^\infty k P_k P(1-P)^N$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. This is looks like what I was trying first. When you remove the terminating sequences from a given $k_s$ you get Fibonacci numbers of order $s$. For example N =5 the number of "permitted sequences" (the ones without 5 consecutive $k_n$) of length $x$ for $x=1, 2, 3, ...$ are $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 61, ...$. It sounds like $P_k$ is going to be another (finite) sum? I can see coming up with a way to calculate the number of sequences of length $k_s$ for a given $N$. I don't see any way to calculate the probability for each of the sequences of length $k_s$.

Comment: For an individual $k_s$ I could (manually), but  I am not sure what the generalized formula would be for $P_k$

Comment: @MiraMath:  You do *not* get the Fibonacci numbers of order $s$.  Frankly, I cannot see how or why you somehow think this.  If you're so convinced, please write two or three paragraphs in your original question to prove this.  I certainly don't believe it, and I doubt anyone else does.  We can't help you if there is such a fundamental disagreement.  I look forward to your explanation.

Comment: @MiraMath:  This has nothing whatsoever to do with Fibonacci... and now that you've failed to show in your problem what the Fibonacci sequence *is* and has any relevance to your problem, I'm worried you're just drifting and flailing around.  I won't provide any more help until you answer the explicit question about Fibonacci.  Bye bye.

Comment: I am trying to enumerate the number of sequences (leading up to the final $N$ days) of a given length that don't prematurely terminate. An example is for $N=5$ I see there are 4 such sequences of length 3: 
$$\{k_r,k_r,k_r\}, \{k_r,k_r,k_s\}, \{k_r,k_s,k_r\}, \{k_r,k_s,k_s\}$$
As soon as I consider sequences of length 6 you would expect $2^5-1=31$ sequences. The one being removed being the case of $\{k_s,k_s,k_s,k_s,k_s\}$
I am doing these manually in an effort to find a pattern. I am not looking for Fibonacci numbers, I plugged the counts I am getting into OEIS and that's what came up.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment is supposed to be listing $k_n$ in the 4 sequences, not $k_s$.The reason I am looking for this pattern is I was hoping knowing the number of sequences of length $k$ would lead me to an expression for $P_k$.I am not trying to irritate you here, and am thankful for the help. To summarize (and let me know if this still does not make sense): The count of valid sequences (strings of $k_r$ and $k_n$) where the max number of consecutive $k_n<N$(premature termination) is giving me Fibonacci numbers. Do you not get 31 when considering the sequences of length 6 where N=5?

Comment: It does *not* give you the Fibonnaci numbers, and merely stating this again and again (without showing it explicitly) doesn't make it true.

Comment: I stated it again, because you asked how I was getting them. I would not be surprised in the least if I was wrong. I am not saying it is true. I am saying it is what I am arriving at. Am I at least correct in saying that there are 31 valid sequences of $k_r$ and $k_n$ of length 6 when $N=5$?